# console.dir(window) in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, browser, firebug

`console.dir(window)` in Chrome:

http://ecmazing.com/unsorted/console-dir-window-in-chrome.png

`console.dir(window)` in Firebug (in Firefox 7):

http://ecmazing.com/unsorted/console-dir-window-in-firebug.png

Why does Firebug list only a couple of properties of the `window` object? How can I list all global properties in Firefox?

Also, where is the `__proto__` property so that I can follow the prototype chain?

Comment: I'm going to shift to Chrome as my main JS developing and debugging tool. Cause I found no answer to this.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem Firebug is filtering out properties that don't satisfy `hasOwnProperty`. For example, when investing the DOM using Firefox 4/Firebug 1.7, `navigator` and `addHandler` show up, but `confirm` does not. Observe:

```
>>> window.hasOwnProperty('confirm')
false
>>> window.hasOwnProperty('addHandler')
true
>>> window.hasOwnProperty('navigator')
true
```

However, `Date` does not show up, and:

```
>>> window.hasOwnProperty('Date')
true
```

So it also seems to be filtering out global constructors, which seems to be confirmed by [comment 9](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4236#c9) on [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4236&q=DOM%20missing&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Test%20Summary). I do not know what function(s) is/are used for filtering these constructors out.

Either way, I have not found a way to work around this. If I do, I'll let you know, but I think there's just no way to do what you want at the moment of writing.

Comment: So basically, it sucks. Chrome's `console.dir(window)` is the real deal - it lists everything (several hundred properties) and lets you follow the prototype chain up to `Object.prototype`.

Comment: What is `addHandler`? That's not a global property afaik.

Comment: @Šime Yes, that unfortunately seems like an apt conclusion. Strangely enough, I cannot find any information on `addHandler`, not even in Mozilla's excellent Javascript documentation. It looks like it might have been something specific to that page - when I add `window.addHandler` manually through the console it shows up in the DOM tab. It all seems pretty contradictory, maybe you should consider filing a bug report with Firebug, I'm sure they can answer in more detail.

Comment: In my Firebug `window.hasOwnProperty('addHandler')` evaluates to `false`. The page you were running the console on probably just augmented the `window` (global) object with a `addHandler` function (probably as a shortcut for `addEventListener`). Web-pages usually introduce global properties (although it should be avoided) - that's why I've run the console on a test page with no JavaScript code on (see my question).

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of options seem to be hidden / disabled by default ..

To the right of the letters DOM on the dom tab (while it is selected) of 
firebug 1.9.0b1 ( and 1.8 im sure..), there is a downward arrow.

Clicking that and selecting all options in the top section (I.E. all apart from "Show Own Properties Only" and "Show Enumerable Properties Only") allowed us to see some otherwise hidden properties.

Im sure the default behaviour used to be to show all properties, and I'm not sure when they changed it but it was pretty frustrating until we found those options.

Hopefully this helps anyone else googling what I just did, trying to figure out why you can get absolutely no useful information out of the DOM Panel of firebug at all.

Answer (score 0):

In FireFox, you can get the full set of window properties with `console.log(window);` But this will essentially point you to the DOM tab for that object, which shows you the current properties of the object.

Using `console.dir(window);` instead gives you a snap-shot of the properties of the object at the specific runtime you requested it.  If you look you can click the last instance of "window" in your FireFox `console.dir(window);` result to see the properties tied to the window object at the time of the function call.

Comment: That will link to the DOM tab of Firebug. But that still only lists 40-50 properties. Where is the rest? The ECMAScript global properties are missing. Also, all methods are missing.

Comment: Hmm yeah, you're right, I'm trying to find "window.Date" in the FireFox object print out, but can't... though you can see it clearly in the Chrome print out.